# How to reset editor for fields in Model View in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a web page in which i can input values. For that, i have provided code something like this

```
<td colspan="2">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line1, new { id= "txtLine1" })
</td>
```

which creates an editor field in the view in the web page for Address Line1. Now , on click of reset button, i want whatever is filled in the editor for Line1, it should be cleared. For this i am using a reset button and javascript as below

```
<input type="button" value="reset" id="btnReset" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnReset").click(function () {           
            $("#txtLine1").val("");     
        });
     });
</script>
```

but this is not working for me. Have tried a lot, googled a lot but no solution seems to work. have even tried giving input type= "reset". Please provide the best solution for this

Comment: You code seems to be working fine.. check **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ozp3h7x3/1/)**

Comment: i am on a corporate network. I do not know why it is not working here

Comment: can you confirm that the click function is being called? Maybe put an alert in there. I know that the doc ready function doesn't fire everytime in some cases.

Comment: yes its confirmed that click function is working fine. i did put an alert to check myself earlier.

Comment: Izzy i think because of editorfor field it is not working. What you have given is a simple input field

Comment: I need a solution to make it work for the editorfor field

Comment: @Rahul if you look into your browser code by hiting F12 you'll see that `EditorFor` will infact be an `input`. `EditFor` renders the appropriate html based on the model property. If you don't want to use `EditorFor` you can change it to `TextBoxFor(model => model.Line1,new {id= "txtLine1"})`

Comment: You do not have an element with `id="txtLine1"` (your use of `new { id= "txtLine1" }` does not add an `id` attribute). Its `$("#Line1").val("");`

Comment: awesome guys StephenMuecke and @Wheels73.. your solution worked :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the Editorfor control by the id that you've specified in the html attributes. "txtLine1". If you look at the html generated, its "Line1" as per your model binding.

Change to the below and it works fine.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnReset").click(function () {
            $("#Line1").val("");
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to put the code inside element if it contains only one line, instead of creating new function.

see, maybe this code works for you.

```
<input id="btnReset" type="button" value="reset" 
        onclick="javascript: $('#Line1').val('');" />
```

Comment: @Izzy I agree, You are right but if you have just one line to execute when button pressed, then it's easy to add code inside element. it become easy when you have a page contains full of single line statements.

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out what is the problem is with your snippet code. You're giving an id to your `EditFor()` which is not being rendered. You're nearly there and you're using the correct `overload` too. You'll need to make use of `htmlAttributes` if you want to assign a custom id to your input. So change your code from

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line1, new { id= "txtLine1" })
```

To

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtLine1" } })
```

I have tested this on my local machine and it works as you want it to.